# Making a macro for more than one key press

Tags: sequence, autohotkey

im pretty new to autohotkey.

Im trying to make something like this.

```
+q::            ( pressing shift+q to launch the macro )
send q
sleep
send w
sleep
send e
sleep
send r
sleep
send f
sleep
send +q
```

What happen with me is i keep spaming those buttons. And i want it to just stop after the last one, and not like "cancel" but just do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't know what you are doing, do you?
Put return at the end.

```
+q::
  send q
  sleep, 100
  send w
  sleep, 100
  send e
  sleep, 100
  send r
  sleep, 100
  send f
  sleep, 100
  send +q
return
```

Comment: As stated above. Im pretty new to this ^^

Comment: So, uh, did you try it?